# Get viewer of a View Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, view, refresh, viewer, sirius

I try to refresh my Sirius Project programmatically like it refreshs if I'm press F5. `project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new NullProgressMonitor())` doesn't refresh the project the way I want, so I checked out what the `org.eclipse.ui.actions.RefreshAction` does. I found out that `org.eclipse.ui.actions.RefreshAction` use the following code snippet

```java
shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        StructuredViewer viewer = getActionSite().getStructuredViewer();
            if (viewer != null && viewer.getControl() != null && !viewer.getControl().isDisposed()) {
                viewer.refresh();
            }
        }
});
```

to refresh the modelexplorer view like i want to.
My problem right now is that I got the modelexplorer view, but don't know how I access the viewer from it, to refresh the view. Does anyone got any clue how to do it?

Comment: That code is only valid for an action defined on a view using the common navigator framework and extending `CommonActionProvider`. There is no general way to get the viewer, you will have to look at the explorer to see what it uses.

Comment: what exactly do u mean with look at the explorer, should I look for away to refresh the `ModelExplorerView` without a viewer?

Comment: I mean you will have to look at the documentation and perhaps even the source code of the viewer to see if it provides a way to do this (it may not provide a way).

Comment: ok i will do that thank you for your advice :D